# Sort by closest date to dates which have occured and will occur

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, momentjs

I have an array of objects, each containing a date field.
I want to sort this array by date in the order of closest date of today.

This must apply to dates which have occured and will occur.

```
res.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(a.toDate) > new Date(b.toDate) ? -1 : new Date(a.toDate) < new Date(b.toDate) ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

I'm currently using this sort function but its only sorting by date.
How am i supposed to do this?

Comment: you dont need new Date

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the absolute delta of the dates and today for sorting.

```js
var array = [{ toDate: '2017-11-01' }, { toDate: '2017-11-02' }, { toDate: '2017-11-03' }, { toDate: '2017-11-04' }, { toDate: '2017-10-01' }, { toDate: '2017-10-11' }, { toDate: '2017-10-31' }, { toDate: '2017-09-01' }, { toDate: '2017-09-20' }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(a.toDate)) - Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(b.toDate));
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the difference betwen toDate and today's date in milliseconds, both for a and b, and compare the differences:

```js
var now = new Date();
now = now.getTime();        // now in ms
res.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aToDate = (new Date(a.toDate)).getTime();
    var bToDate = (new Date(b.toDate)).getTime();
    return Math.abs(aToDate - now) - Math.abs(bToDate - now);
});
```